# rendering an AngularJS detail view within list view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm a little new to the AngularJS world, and I'm wondering what the best way is to show a resource detail view within a list view.

Given a path like `/people`, I would just show a list of people resources.  If I were to navigate from one of those people to a url like `people/john-doe`, I can easily get a detail view and all the data associated with that person.  But how can I do this without leaving the list view?  I'd like to somehow append the detail to the list, or show it within the list, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is nested views, which isn't something that the regular ngRoute library does well. I advise you check out [angular-ui router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).

Comment: Under the statesProvider of angularjs...u can specify multiple views or nested views in the "routes" or "states" js file. There are aome examples provided online as well.